# setInterval : unexpected behaviour when passing functions as parameters

Tags: javascript, constants, setinterval

Function declarations:

```
const getDate = () => {
  return new Date();
}
const seconds = (date) => {
  return date.getSeconds();
}
const minutes = (date) =>{
  return date.getMinutes();
}
const hours = (date) => {
  return date.getHours();
}
```

These functions are tested and work.

```
setInterval(update,1000,secondHand,seconds(getDate()));
```

Expected behaviour: my update function runs with the new time supplied by seconds(getDate()).

What actually happens: when logging inside the update function, the last parameter remains the same and doesn't get updated. I suspect the function doesn't actually get executed anymore, and the parameter initially entered in the setInterval function is static/unchangeable?

Is this correct? Could someone explain this behavior and how can I avoid it (other than creating yet another function that calls all the functions needed and passing that as the function for the setInterval)?

THanks!

Comment: try `setInterval(function(){ update(); secondHand(); seconds(getDate()); } , 1000);`

Comment: you are right about the fact that the function is evaluated at the creation of the interval and this value is used for each iteration. @Hudson's comment is almost the way to go : `setInterval(function(){ update(secondHand(), seconds(getDate()));  } , 1000);`, Giving us the update method (or at least it's expected parameter) could help us solving your issue

Comment: Your code is equivalent to `const secs = seconds(getDate()); setInterval(() => update(secondHand, secs), 1000);`

Comment: "*creating yet another function that calls all the functions needed and passing that as the function for the setInterval*" - yes, that's exactly the solution. As for "yet another": your current functions are trivial enough to be simply inlined in that function that you should pass to `setInterval`

Comment: @Bergi Indeed. Though I was hoping there would be a 'cleaner' solution. I guess I'll have to settle for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you actually have to send a method to be invoked - a callable... you're actually sending a result. you're invoking the method...
you should try returning another function in the return of your function :) I think it's called partial apply, similar to curry...

Comment: that may work if passing in a method to the last param